# how to use "class_exists" conditional inside if...elseif

Tags: php

I have a chain of if...elseif...else statements likes so:

```
if (!empty($video_meta)) {
    echo 'foo';
} elseif ( WPCOM_Liveblog::is_liveblog_post() ) {
    echo 'bar';
} elseif (has_tag('featured')) {
    echo 'foobar';
}
```

The second elseif statement is reliant on a particular WordPress plugin (liveblog) being activated. In the event that the plugin is not active, the function will throw a fatal error because the class `WPCOM_Liveblog` doesn't exist.

I tried to use a nested IF statement like this

```
if (has_post_format('video')) {
    echo 'foo';
} elseif (class_exists('WPCOM_Liveblog')) {
    if ( WPCOM_Liveblog::is_liveblog_post() ) {
        echo'bar';
    }
} elseif (has_tag('featured')) {
    echo 'foobar';
}
```

If the second condition is false, it never gets to the final elseif for obvious reasons. The `class_exists` condition always evaluates to true and the chain of if statements terminate.

I cannot use a simple `&&` conditional, since I'm looking for a deactivated plugin, and the second condition will simply throw a fatal error for an unknown class.

I also cannot change the order of the if...elseif statements. There is a purpose behind the order.

This feels like a simple PHP question, but I'm stumped. Is there anyway I can nest another condition in the `elseif`? Basically, if the first part of the condition is true, execute the second condition. If both true, return true to the `elseif`. If the class doesn't exist, then the second conditional check never fires.

Comment: you says: "if the first part of the condition is true, execute the second condition" Which is for you first part of condition and second condition? can you explain the last part of your question in your code?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP your conditions are executed in order from left to right so you can do the following:

```
elseif (class_exists('WPCOM_Liveblog') && WPCOM_Liveblog::is_liveblog_post()) {
    echo'bar';
}
```

Proof (via ideone): http://ideone.com/fAN2YK

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could move the test that fails out of the loop:

```
$plugin_loaded = false;
if ( class_exists('WPCOM_Liveblog') ) {
    $plugin_loaded = ( WPCOM_Liveblog::is_liveblog_post() ) ? true : false;
}

if (has_post_format('video')) {
    echo 'foo';
} elseif ($plugin_loaded ) {
    echo 'bar';
} elseif (has_tag('featured')) {
    echo 'foobar';
}
```